# How do I get a variable-length list of strings in an HTML form to Flask with WTForms?

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I am developing a question-and-answer web application with Flask and Flask-WTForms. Questions can have 1 to 5 tags, and I made a tag editor for users to input their tags:

[image: tag input with 2 tags below the input text area]

I've written JavaScript code to serialize the tags into an array. So, in the image above that array looks like this: `["tag1","tag2"]`, and when tag3 gets added, it looks like this: `["tag1","tag2","tag3"]`.

I need a way to get that list of tag names to my Flask view function, but I can't figure out how to do that. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**The form:**

```
class AskQuestionForm(Form):
    title = StringField('Title', validators=[Required(), Length(min=15, max=200)])
    content = TextAreaField('Content', validators=[Required(), Length(min=50, max=30000)])

    submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

**The view function:**

```
@main.route('/ask/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def ask_question():
    form = AskQuestionForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        # Code to add a new question
    else:
        return render_template('ask.html', form=form)
```

**The template (simplified):**

```
<form id="ask-question-form" method="post" action="{{ url_for('main.ask_question') }}">
    {{ form.csrf_token }}

    <label for="title">Title</label>
    <input type="text" name="title" id="title">

    <label for="content">Content</label>
    <textarea name="content" id="content"></textarea>

    <label for="tags">Tags</label>
    <input type="text" name="tags" id="add-tag-input">
    <span>
        <button id="add-tag-button" type="button">Add</button>
    </span>

    <button type="submit">Submit question</button>
</form>
```

---

**How can I get the list of tags to my Flask view function?** Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your input controls don't have any `name` attributes, thus they will never be passed to the server.  Are you sure this is the template you are using?

Comment: Oops, I took a lot of Bootstrap attributes out for readability, and must have gotten the name attributes too. I will update the question.

Comment: could you share you javascript code wich shows tag below form?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `TagListField` which is used an example of creating custom fields in the wtforms [documentation](http://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fields.html#custom-fields). It will take care of what you are trying to do here. I have slightly modified it because in the original example they are using a comma separated string of tags:

```
class TagListField(Field):
    widget = TextInput()

    def _value(self):
        if self.data:
            return u', '.join(self.data)
        else:
            return u''

    def process_formdata(self, valuelist):
        if valuelist:
            self.data = [x.strip() for x in valuelist[0].split(' ')]
        else:
            self.data = []
```

Comment: I'm having trouble integrating this solution into my application. The form won't validate and I'm not sure that my JavaScript is doing the right thing (it clears the input, then puts a comma-separated list of tags - `tag1,tag2,tag3` - into the tags input).

Answer (score 0):

Burhan's answer was part of my solution, but here is what I had to do:

1. I added a hidden field to my form and left the tag input without a name so it wouldn't get submitted.
2. Using JavaScript, I intercepted the form submit and put a comma-separated list of tag names into the hidden field.
3. I created a TagListField with a `process_formdata(self, valuelist)` function similar to what was shown above.
4. In my Flask view function, I retrieved the value of the hidden field and proceeded to use it in making the new question.

If any future readers have any questions about what I did specifically, post a comment.